# Newline not being added in postman API response

Tags: python, api, postman

I have tried multiple ways to get this string(HTML text) in different lines, but I'm not able to do it.
I tried by adding "\n" to the end of the line or using """text""" but none of them worked.

This is the code in python:-

```
        xHTML = "<html>\
                 <head>\
                 <title>"+title+"</title>\
                 <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=rm1--1234\">\
                 </head>\
                 <!--\
                  quotes.\
                 -->\
                 <body>\
                 <param name=\"code\" value=\"" + code + "\">\
                     <param name=\"value1\" value=\"" + val1 + "\">\
                     <param name=\"value2\" value=\"" + val2 + "\">\
                     <param name=\"value3\" value=\"" + val3 + "\">\
                 </body>\
                 </html>"
return {"html":xHTML}
```

and this is the Postman API response I'm seeing

```
"html": "<html>                 <head>                 <title>Values</title>                 <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=rm1--1234\">                 </head>                 <!--                                -->                 <body> <param name=\"value1\" value=\"12\">\ <param name=\"value2\" value=\"13\">\
                     <param name=\"value3\" value=\"14\">\                                  </body>                 </html>"
```

Please help me in printing these HTML tags in different lines.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Triple quotes should work.  Also use f-string to insert variables.

```
xhtml = f"""
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>{title}</title>
    ... and so on
"""
```

Comment: f before the string? sorry but isn't working.

Comment: @RAJMANI Yes.  That makes it an f-string, and you can put `{var}` inside the string to substitute the value of `var`, instead of having to do `"""abc""" + var + """xyz"""`

Comment: F-strings were introduced in Python 3.6.  What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.6.

Comment: You can still use old-style `%s` formatting.

Comment: @RAJMANI If you can, I strongly recommend upgrading to a modern version of Python.  Version 2.6 is _ancient_.